# Can I claim an ownership of a site in google search console independently of other owners

Tags: google-search-console, ownership

I am asking for help with the following problem:

I own a website in Google Search Console (as pe.kmec@gmail.com, along with another owner):

[image: Screenshot 1]

Later on I logged in under my company's name, created a Google Search Console account under my company's name (kopexsro@gmail.com)  and verified kopexsro as the owner of the same website via a HTML tag:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Under pe.kmec@gmail.com I correctly see the search history of the website with any time window. However, under kopexsro@gmail.com  the search history is stuck in the past few days (even though I select "last 3 months"), see screenshot:

[image: Screenshot 3]

Then, I switched to the pe.kmec@gmail.com  account and added kopexsro as another owner (i.e. delegated ownership):

[image: Screenshot 4]

However I still see no traffic under kopexsro.

Could it be because kopexsro was originally added independently of other owners?

And when I delegated the ownership to kopexsro  could it be that the "delegated"  kopexsro  somehow is not recognized as the "original"  kopexsro?

Comment: How long has it been since you logged in under your company account?

Comment: I did the verification for kopexsro@gmail.com  3 days ago  - 11/26/18 2:05:28 PM UTC.  I delegated ownership to kopexsro  an hour ago.

Comment: I would suggest leaving it for a week or two to see if you start seeing the same data under both accounts. Google Search Console is notorious for not showing 'up-to-date' data.

Comment: Thanks Tony, now it works - I added the the property without 'www'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshots show different sites. Some include www, and some don't. The difference of www means a different site, and different performance data.

Comment: To add to this answer, you can group all the data together by using a [property set](https://searchengineland.com/google-search-console-now-lets-group-sites-together-property-sets-250168).