# Transfer Search Console Ownership from one google account to another

Tags: google, google-search-console, gmail

I have 2 google accounts. One has my search console, google analytics and similar services. The other has my gmail account.

I need to move my search console to my gmail account.

What's the best/easiest way to do this?

Comment: There is no any shortcut as far I know. You've to add new user on all of similar service like [Google search console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7687615#manage-owners) and [Google analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702?hl=en)  and then remove the old account which you don't want.

Comment: See also: [Can I claim an ownership of a site in google search console independently of other owners](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/119342/can-i-claim-an-ownership-of-a-site-in-google-search-console-independently-of-oth)

Comment: I would claim the site for the gmail account using their own form of verification. e.g. file, meta tag, Google Analytics owner, DNS setting.You are given the options and instructions if you select add property from the gmails accounts Google Search Console.

Answer (score 3):

Google has upgraded the new UI for Search Console: https://search.google.com/search-console/about

So if you want to transfer the ownership to the new owner, do the followings:

- Log in to your Search console account
- Choose the website and then navigate to **Settings -> Users and Permissions -> Add user**
- Grant the full permission for the new account.
- After that, you log in to the new account and remove the old owner.